# How to compare two ranges in Kotlin?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, find, range

I have one array of ranges and one range that is *min number of ranges Array* .. *max number of ranges Array*

How can i find number, that is not used in my Big Range?

for example:
`[1..3, 4..6, 8..10]`
and Amount range will be `1..10`

And `7` is not in one of ranges in Arr. How can I find it?

```
    import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

    repeat(scanner.nextInt()) {

        val listOfRange = mutableListOf<IntRange>()
        var min = Int.MAX_VALUE
        var max = Int.MIN_VALUE

        repeat(scanner.nextInt()) {
            listOfRange.add(scanner.nextInt()..scanner.nextInt())
        }

        for (i in listOfRange) {
            if (min > i.first) min = i.first
            if (max < i.last) max = i.last
        }
        val maxRange = min .. max

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `7` is not in any of the ranges? `9` would be covered by `8..10`, right?

Comment: yes, sorry, it was late night :)

Answer (score 2):

To find number that is in listOfRange but in listOfRange you can use  flatten:

```
val newList = listOfRange.minus(listOfRange.flatten())
```

Comment: just putting in a full example: 
fun main() {
    val rangeList = listOf(1..3, 4..6, 8..10)
    val completeList = 1..10
    println(completeList.minus(rangeList.flatten()))
    // OR
    println(completeList.filter { it !in rangeList.flatten() })
}

Comment: Thank you. Here should be maxRange